# How to connect MongoDB to Openshift?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

I have a NodeJS Express app that uses Mongoose for MongoDB. I'm confused as to how to connect it to the OpenShift database. For development, I'm connecting to a local database, which works fine. Here's what I have:

```
//====== MONGODB SETUP ======
mongo_url = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST+":"+parseInt(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT);

if(app.dev){
    mongo_url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/my-db";
}

app.modules.mongoose.connect(mongo_url);
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

You need more than just host and port. You have to provide username and password.
A simpler way for it is to use:

```
mongo_url = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL;
```

OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL has username and password too.

Comment: can I connect other then default DB in OpenShift?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337433/connect-to-other-then-default-db-in-openshift

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide **username** and **password** and the **database** name along with *host* and *port*.

So you can try appending OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME to the OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL.

```
mongo_url = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL+process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
```

---

```
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL has the below format:
(e.g. mongodb://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/)
```