# auth fails: Connect to other then default DB in OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

Am I allowed to use other MongoDB database in `OpenShift` or just the default one indicated in web interface?

Somehow I created a database called Memrise, but it seems **I don't have access to DB called 'Memrise' from Node.js only from MongoDB client, but I can connect to DB called 'nodesjs'**.

this is the connection string used in `Node.js`

```
mongodb://admin:xxx@127.8.202.130:27017/Memrise
Db open error: auth fails
```

here is how I try to connect:

```
console.log(connection_string + '/' + req.params.db);
         connection.connect(connection_string + '/' + req.params.db, function (err, db) {

                            if (err) {
                            //logger.error('Db open error: ' + err.message);
                            console.log('Db open error: ' + err.message);
                            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
                            return;
                            }
```

web interface about MongoDB, you can see the 'default' DB is called 'nodejs'
[image]

and here are all the DBs able to see in MongoDB client, 'Memrise' is in list:

[image]

So am I able to access other DB in `OpenShift` or only default one?

Comment: authenticate to the database where the user was created, you can switch then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26428737/239219

Comment: solution here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/connecting/ **Indirectly Against Another Database** need `'?authSource=admin'` at the end of the connection string

Comment: For what it's worth you can also use RockMongo to admin your OpenShift MongoDB instance: https://hub.openshift.com/addons/29-rockmongo